# Preserving type when using Object.keys()

Tags: typescript, static-typing

I have an object with typed keys, let's call them Statuses (`StatusesType`).
I need to iterate over the object and pass keys to some method expecting parameter of the same type `StatusesType`, let it be `statusPrinter()`

```
type StatusesType = 'PENDING' | 'APPROVED' | 'REJECTED';
type SomeMap = {
    [key in StatusesType]?: number
}

const STATUSES: SomeMap = {
    PENDING: 5,
    REJECTED: 2,
};

function statusPrinter(val: StatusesType) {
    console.log('- ', val);
}

Object.keys(STATUSES).forEach(status => {
    statusPrinter(status);
});
```

But when I call `statusPrinter(status);` TypeScript returns this error

`error TS2345: Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'StatusesType'.`

How can I pass this key preserving type?

I know that I can force TS with this `statusPrinter(<StatusesType>status);` but I think it is the last thing I should do and I would prefer native solution.

**Update:** If it is not possible to iterate over object keys with `Object.keys()` preserving type - what options do I have? Is there a way to iterate over keys preserving types at all, and if so - which way is the best? I am not fixing on `Object.keys()` but I would like to keep original object structure.

Thanks!

Comment: *How can I pass this key preserving type?* I don't think you can. `keys` will always be string. You can try to use `for (let key:StatusesType in STATUSES )` and try, but I doubt it would work.

Comment: Why Object.keys isn't typed: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/12253#issuecomment-263132208. How about `.forEach((status: StatusesType) => {`?

Comment: I've updated the question.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, It actually works, and could be a... well if not a solution still good kin of workaround. I would prefer not to specify type, but if it is an only option - still good. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Short and typesafe solution using the built-in ES2015 `Map` class:

```
type StatusesType = 'PENDING' | 'APPROVED' | 'REJECTED';

const STATUSES = new Map<StatusesType, number>([
    ['PENDING', 5],
    ['REJECTED', 2],
]);

function statusPrinter(val: StatusesType) {
    console.log('- ', val);
}

STATUSES.forEach((_, status) => statusPrinter(status));
```

Comment: Oh, this is good. It requires little more typing than I expected but it is type-safe.

Comment: Probably the best suggestion,
Avoid using `Object.keys` as it requires casting (casting is dangerous)
Using a custom iterator function as suggested here is okay, a little ugly to my taste, but also does the work

Answer (score 4):

Object.keys will return an array of keys and keys are of type string.

So signature of `Object.keys` would be `key(object: {}): Array<string>`. So when you loop over keys, `status` is of type string and not `StatusesType`.

You can cast the type though as `statusPrinter(status as StatusesType)`

#### Reference Link:

- [Typescript: cast an object to other type](http://acdcjunior.github.io/typescript-cast-object-to-other-type-or-instanceof.html)

Comment: As I mentioned in my question - I know that I can case but I do not want to cast, I am looking for native way of passing type...

Answer (score 2):

You can do that with iterator like this:

```
function iterator<M, K extends keyof M>(map: M, cb: (key: keyof M, value: M[K]) => void) {
  Object.keys(map).forEach((key: K) => cb(key, map[key]))
}

iterator(STATUSES, status => {
    statusPrinter(status);
});
```

Comment: Also good: Does not require using `Map` but little less convenient because in case if I need also value TypeScript would recognize `STATUSES[status]` in loop as potential `undefined`, because of the way object type is defined `[key in StatusesType]?`.

Comment: iterator function seems to have type errors: https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-leakey-93zb3?file=/src/index.ts

Comment: I get multiple type errors in the iterator function. type M does not work with the signature of Object.keys and it can't type key in the forEach lambda. See the codesandbox link of @QuangVan